# How do I call this getUser function elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

```
export default defineStore("user", () => {
  const loadingStore = useLoadingStore();
  const successStore = useSuccessStore();
  const errorStore = useErrorStore();

  const user = ref(null);
  const token = ref(!!window.localStorage.getItem(`${env}token`) || null);

  return {
    // state
    user,
    token,

    // getters
    getUser: computed(() => user),
    getToken: computed(() => token),
```

This is a code snippet for a function that I am currently working with. My issue is that I am not too sure how to approach calling the getters (getUser) in another Vue file.

```
import  defineStore  from "@/store/user.js"

const store = defineStore();
const user = store.getUser();
```

This is what I've tried doing in the Vue file and I got an error in my browser console saying that it doesn't recognise the store.getUser as a function. How do I access the getUser function?

Comment: That's because computes accepts a callback that computes the value and returns reactive value not a getter. getUser is not a function in your example. If you want it to be function make computed value callback return a function

Comment: The example doesn't show how you use "user". You don't need to call getUser() at all, it's not a function, as said